# Drupal SEO friendly URL's when promoting to front page

Tags: drupal

When I promote a page to the front page in Drupal, the link that says "read more" on the home page points to `node/11`.

I have Pathauto enabled and the checkbox under that article's publish settings is checked for 'Generate automatic URL alias'

I would like the "read more" button to point to the friendly URL.

If I manually navigate to the friendly URL it works, just the link on the homepage is linking to 'node/11'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds distinctly like your theme or a module is overriding those links.  When Drupal generates the links dynamically, (as with core or most contributed themes/modules) it automatically uses the path alias.

Another place to look is if you're using a custom view (using the views module) for the homepage (as opposed to Drupal's default which is rendered by the node module), you may have configured the view to output the link in a way that it won't get rewritten as well.

I'd suggest switching to the Garland or Bartik theme (depending on your version) and see how they're output.  If they're still not using the alias, then a module is overriding them (no core module will do this, and almost all contrib module won't either, so it's likely a custom module or a view).

Comment: It was a custom module. Finally found the file and replaced the link with drupal_lookup_path('alias',"node/".$row->nid) Thanks for the help.